# With a fresh browser session, initial login must be done a second time after navigating to another page

Tags: php

I am using a login system that malfunctions when a fresh browser session is opened.  It appears to happen across all browsers.  Here's what happens:

1. I open a new browser session.
2. I enter a user name and password, and I am logged in just fine.
3. I navigate to another page (any page), and I am no longer logged in (this is bad - not what I want).
4. I enter a user name and password, and I am logged in just fine.
5. I navigate elsewhere, and I am still logged in (this is good - this is what I want).
6. During the same browser session, the log-in / log-out works fine.  I can even log in with different usernames and navigate freely and all functions as it should.

This happens every time I open a new browser window.  So basically, I have to do the initial log-in twice for the first username I user per browser session.  Then, everything works just fine, even for multiple users.

Any idea why this might be happening?

The code I am using is below.

Thanks in advance,

John

login.php:

```
<?php
if (!isLoggedIn())
{
    // user is not logged in.
    if (isset($_POST['cmdlogin']))
    {
        // retrieve the username and password sent from login form & check the login.
        if (checkLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
        {
            show_userbox();


        } else
        {
            echo "Incorrect Login information !";
            show_loginform();
        }
    } else
    {
        // User is not logged in and has not pressed the login button
        // so we show him the loginform
        show_loginform();
    }

} else
{
    // The user is already loggedin, so we show the userbox.
    show_userbox();


}


?>
```

Show Login Form Function:

```
function show_loginform($disabled = false)
{

    echo '<form name="login-form" id="login-form" method="post" action="./index.php?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].'"> 

    <div class="usernameformtext"><label title="Username">Username: </label></div> 
    <div class="usernameformfield"><input tabindex="1" accesskey="u" name="username" type="text" maxlength="30" id="username" /></div> 


    <div class="passwordformtext"><label title="Password">Password: </label></div> 
    <div class="passwordformfield"><input tabindex="2" accesskey="p" name="password" type="password" maxlength="15" id="password" /></div> 


    <div class="registertext"><a href="http://www...com/.../register.php" title="Register">Register</a></div> 
    <div class="lostpasswordtext"><a href="http://www...com/.../lostpassword.php" title="Lost Password">Lost password?</a></div> 

  <p class="loginbutton"><input tabindex="3" accesskey="l" type="submit" name="cmdlogin" value="Login" ';
    if ($disabled == true)
    {
        echo 'disabled="disabled"';
    }
    echo ' /></p></form>';


}
```

Login functions:

```
<?php

#### Login Functions #####


function isLoggedIn()
{

    if (session_is_registered('loginid') && session_is_registered('username'))
    {
        return true; // the user is loged in
    } else
    {
        return false; // not logged in
    }

    return false;

}

function checkLogin($u, $p)
{
global $seed; // global because $seed is declared in the header.php file

    if (!valid_username($u) || !valid_password($p) || !user_exists($u))
    {
        return false; // the name was not valid, or the password, or the username did not exist
    }

    //Now let us look for the user in the database.
    $query = sprintf("
        SELECT loginid 
        FROM login 
        WHERE 
        username = '%s' AND password = '%s' 
        AND disabled = 0 AND activated = 1 
        LIMIT 1;", mysql_real_escape_string($u), mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($p . $seed)));
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    // If the database returns a 0 as result we know the login information is incorrect.
    // If the database returns a 1 as result we know  the login was correct and we proceed.
    // If the database returns a result > 1 there are multple users
    // with the same username and password, so the login will fail.
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 1)
    {
        return false;
    } else
    {
        // Login was successfull
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        // Save the user ID for use later
        $_SESSION['loginid'] = $row['loginid'];
        // Save the username for use later
        $_SESSION['username'] = $u;
        // Now we show the userbox
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
function isLoggedIn()
{

    if (isset($_SESSION['loginid']) && isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
        return true; // the user is loged in
    } 
    else
    {
        return false; // not logged in
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but when I tried your suggestion, the site came up as a blank page.

Comment: Sorry, just to be sure. I meant replace your isLoggedIn() function with the one i provided, is that what you tried?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did.  I was surprised to see that just doing that made the entire site just a blank screen.  I guess this function is important.

Comment: you need to add some debugging to see where in your script it is failing. make sure you have error reporting turned on too. i would start a fresh browser session or drop all session cookies too

Comment: Okay, the first time around, I didn't correctly implement your suggestion.  So the blank screen was my fault.  When I put in exactly what you suggest, the site works like it did before.  However, the problem I mention above still persists.  I did see in the PHP manual that session_is_registered has been deprecated, so I am going to stick with your code.  So your suggestion has helped me to use up-to-date PHP.  Thanks.

Comment: when it fails the first time round, have you checked where *exactly* its failing? guessing its probably where in your code it says "// User is not logged in and has not pressed the login button
so we show him the loginform"